# Split text into pages in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I’m looking for a way to split an article (long text) with images into pages (screens). Something like a book reader. I need it to support different screen heights. Please share if anyone has seen something similar.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try with react-native-pager-view library. Passing your content in array.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pager-view

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';

const ArticleReader = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Image
        source={item.image}
        style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}
      />
      <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <PagerView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {articleContent.map((item, index) => (
        <View key={index.toString()}>{renderItem({ item })}</View>
      ))}
    </PagerView>
  );
};

export default ArticleReader;
```

Let me know is it working for you or not.